# xsl:for-each-group with a condition producing extra output

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am working on to produce text output file from an xml. The XML entries will have a node called as LoanAmt whose value could be 0 or more than zero. Now, I have to check two conditions, first of which is to see if the value of LoanAmt is greater than 0, and then if it is I have to sum up the entries of LoanAmt if for unique Participant enntries. In other words if there is only one Participant ID in the whole xml then display the output but if there are more than one Partcipant ID then only one record for each unique Particpant ID should be populated but the LoanAmt within each unique Particpant ID should be summed up and displayed.  My issue is that my xslt is working the same way as I want but the groupby and if condition is not working on the first entry of xml where Loan Amt is not greater than zero. So, the first entry that I am getting is being displayed with zero amount and this line should not appear.

This is the XML which is not the complete set but I have taken a sample out of the original one :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Report_Data >
    <Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>033</Participant_ID>
    <chk>673.58</chk>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>Vana</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>Sag</First_Name>
        <Middle_Name>N</Middle_Name>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>100.8</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>100.8</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>0</LoanAmt>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>037</Participant_ID>
    <chk>2167.89</chk>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>Pilay</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>Saath</First_Name>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>61.81</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>61.81</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>0</LoanAmt>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>043</Participant_ID>
    <chk>819.78</chk>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>ouphan</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>angmala</First_Name>
        <Gender_Code>2</Gender_Code>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>84.19</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>84.18</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>0</LoanAmt>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>049</Participant_ID>
    <chk>2066.54</chk>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>Tizili</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>ard</First_Name>
        <Gender_Code>1</Gender_Code>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>136.37</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>136.36</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>0</LoanAmt>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>094</Participant_ID>
    <chk>946.71</chk>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>holphakdy</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>Meya</First_Name>
        <Gender_Code>2</Gender_Code>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>81.25</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>81.25</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>0</LoanAmt>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>104</Participant_ID>
    <chk>1183.3</chk>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>Sai</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>Paupl</First_Name>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>234.52</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>234.52</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>128.18</LoanAmt>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>106</Participant_ID>
    <chk>185.44</chk>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>Leve</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>Alen</First_Name>
        <Middle_Name>S</Middle_Name>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>61.48</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>61.47</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>0</LoanAmt>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>106</Participant_ID>
    <chk>0</chk>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>Leve</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>Alen</First_Name>
        <Middle_Name>S</Middle_Name>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>0</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>0</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>10</LoanAmt>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>131</Participant_ID>
    <chk>508.92</chk>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>th</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>Pa</First_Name>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>0</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>0</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>0</LoanAmt>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>153</Participant_ID>
    <chk>277.2</chk>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>Baer</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>Er</First_Name>
        <Middle_Name>D</Middle_Name>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>72.39</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>72.38</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>0</LoanAmt>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>155</Participant_ID>
    <chk>1250.83</chk>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>Piye</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>Shirit</First_Name>
        <Middle_Name>M</Middle_Name>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>0</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>0</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>96.3</LoanAmt>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>170</Participant_ID>
    <chk>0</chk>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>terner</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>san</First_Name>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>0</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>0</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>0</LoanAmt>
</Report_Entry>
<Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>170</Participant_ID>
    <chk>684.05</chk>
    <Workers>
        <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        <Last_Name>terner</Last_Name>
        <First_Name>san</First_Name>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>162.31</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>162.3</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>210.98</LoanAmt>
     </Report_Entry>
```

I am putting my xslt that I have used :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com"  >


   <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"/>
   <xsl:variable name="filler" select="'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    '"/>
   <xsl:variable name="separator" select="','"/>
   <xsl:variable name="spaces"
   select="concat('          ','          ','          ','          ','          ','          ','          ','          ','          ')"/>




  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:call-template name="LoanDataRecord"/>

  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="LoanDataRecord">

   <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Data/Report_Entry" group-by="if(  LoanAmt[. &gt;  0 ] ) then Participant_ID else '' " >      
   <xsl:variable name="Var1" select="current-grouping-key()"/> 

    <!-- Plan Number -->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat('768002',$filler),1,6)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>


    <!-- Participant Number -->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(Participant_ID,$filler),1,9)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>

    <!-- Loan Amt -->
    <xsl:value-of select="(sum(current-group()/LoanAmt))"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/> 

    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

768002,033709571,0

768002,104603206,128.18

and so on

But I do not want to see the first line which has 0 LoanAmt.

Comment: Can you please post the complete XSLT here.

Comment: My xslt contains sensitive data and has around 200 plus records  hence I wont be able to paste it completely. Is it absolutely necesary for my question ? Will you be willing to take this offline ?

Comment: You needn't post your real-time XSLT.. You can create a minimized input XML, and an XSLT that can represent the very problem here, which I guess is grouping.

Comment: Added the complete xslt and also added little extensive set of the xml .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `<xsl:for-each-group />` instruction. Change it to use a predicate:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Data/Report_Entry[LoanAmt &gt; 0 ]" 
                    group-by="Participant_ID">
```

I tested it with your XML, and it works: http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWu.

By the way, I added `<xsl:output method="text" />`, as that's what you probably want.

Comment: Can you please explain me why with my code it was not grouping just the first record and was not even checking the loan greater than 0 condition and instead came inside the loop to print the values. But from next iteration it was checking the condition and grouping correctlly.

Comment: Your code was creating an extra group with `grouping-key == ''` containing all records that didn't match the `LoanAmt &gt; 0` condition (due to the `else` clause you had). Since all such records had `LoanAmt == 0`, the grand total for that group was also 0. But if you change some records to `LoanAmt` -1, -2, -3, etc. You'll see that the first record would produce a sum of those (a value different to 0).

Comment: Thanks for the neat  explanation!

Comment: @SudhaRani, you can upvote it if you liked it ;-) Thanks!

Comment: @SudhaRani There is a little "up" arrow that appears on the left of the comment when you place your pointer around that area ;-) https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-now-with-flags-and-votes/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100698/discussion-between-sudha-rani-and-raulk).